# How to automatically select the interface as the default gateway based on internet connectivity?

Tags: networking, network-interface, gateway

I have two interfaces (one wired and one wireless) where both gets their IP via dhcp and any of them might or might not have an internet connection.

I need to create a fallback mechanism that prefers an interface for the internet connection but it should change the preferred interface if current one lost the connection and the other now has the internet connection.

Is there a mechanism in Linux for this kind of requirement or should I need to write a script that alters the routing table accordingly?

Comment: You could use a routing metric and then have two default route entries. The one with the lower metric will be preferred

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `ifmetric` (`sudo apt-get install ifmetric`).

With `sudo ifmetric wlan0 50` for example you can assign the metric to the wlan0 card with value of 50. The lower the number, the higher the priority for the connection.

With `route -n` you can see metrics configured in your system (Metric field).
The change will be reflected immediately.

Comment: This `ifmetric` command is useful. However, it still doesn't behave "it sets the priority" because if `eth0` is available, it still doesn't use the `wlan0` interface. Am I supposed to write a script that pings a server and sets the `metric` based on the success?

Comment: Yes It's a good idea. If your script works post it if you want. I'm interested.